# "You don't have the permission to use this type of flag"

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

In the [Flagged Posts queue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=flags), I choose the "it has invalid flags" option. I receive this message:

[image: You don't have the permission to use this type of flag]

I most certainly should have this permission. Certainly I have before now. The flagging dialog also informs me I have 97 flags left to use today.

This has happened on more than one flagged post today.

Comment: This will have to wait for a dev, I think.

Comment: I'll look into it, please follow up [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215481/what-does-you-dont-have-the-permission-to-use-this-type-of-flag-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Meta post [What does "You don't have the permission to use this type of flag" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215481/what-does-you-dont-have-the-permission-to-use-this-type-of-flag-mean)

> Figured it out. It happened only when the user hit the flags tab via the `/tools` route, since it was the last `/tools` tab he had open.
>
> Fixed in next build that rolls out (before that happens you can simply work around by clicking visiting `/tools/flagged`). Watch for build rev `2014.1.9.1836` on meta and `2014.1.9.1287` on sites.